# Prometheus Alertmanager Expression Problem/Question(s) concerning Lists

Tags: expression, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to create an prometheus-alert-expression that checks if a mountpoint is mounted and sends an alert if the mountpoint is missing .. The Idea was something like this:

```
groups:
  - name: mountpoints 
    rules:
      - alert: /ghome missing 
        expr: absent(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/ghome", instance="my.machine.org:9100"}) 
        for: 60s
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "/ghome missing on ({{ $labels.instance }})."
          description: "VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```

This kinda works. But is there a way of passing a list/vector to the mountpoint(s) and/or instance(s).

Using this Expression I'll have to write an alert-rule for each instance and each mountpoint.

I had the Idea of trying regular-Expressions like

```
    expr: absent(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint=~"/ghome|/something|/other", instance=~"my.machine.org:9100|another.machine.org:9100"})
```

.. but this obviously does not work.

Does anybody have an idea how to implement this ?

Greetings

Volker

Answer (score 0):

When we pass an expression such as `absent(my_metric{label=~"1|2"})`, this is evaluated as such:
`my_metric{label=~"1|2"}` might return 4 possible results:

1. No result
2. my_metric{label="1"}
3. my_metric{label="2"}
4. both my_metric{label="1"} and my_metric{label="2"}

And the `absent` function is then called upon these results, and for absent to return "1" it will only do so when there are no results. Missing the case when 1 of them is absent.

Unfortunately there's no one-liner for this, we'll have to be explict with absent, we can either have multiple alert-rules or use the `or` operator such as:

`absent(my_metric{label="1"}) or absnet(my_metrci{label="2"})`

Comment: Ok U'll keep that in mind .. thank that helps at least to reduce the Rules .. therefore I am using a few Rules like:
`
absent(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="foo.bar.de:9100",mountpoint="/homex"}) or absent(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="foo.bar.de:9100",mountpoint="/homey"}) or
absent(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="foo.bar.de:9100",mountpoint="/homez"}) or .....
`
Do you have any alternative Idea, how to check if a mountpoint exists ?

Comment: there must be other creative ways, but I think this is the most straightforward one.